# SVG Mask not rendering on page

Tags: svg

I created a simple SVG star image and a applied a mask to it.  When I put the code into CodePen it looks as it should.  So does when I test at W3 Schools and RapidTools.com, however the SVG code when used on my website does not mask correctly.  It is not masking at all.  Here is my SVG:

```html
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 256 256" width="256" height="256">
    
        <mask id="half" x="0" y="0">
        <rect fill="white" height="100%" width="36%" y="0"></rect>
      </mask>
    
        <path d="M167.55 84.26L256 97.79L192 163.38L207.11 256L128 212.26L48.89 256L64 163.38L0 97.79L88.45 84.26L128 0L167.55 84.26Z" id="b2cMUKCN2H" fill="#f3cc4a" mask="url(#half)"></path>
          <path d="M167.25 84.61L255 98.02L191.5 163.1L206.49 255L128 211.61L49.51 255L64.5 163.1L1 98.02L88.76 84.61L128 1L167.25 84.61Z" id="amyYzznmg" stroke="#9e9e9e" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0"></path>
    
      </svg>
```

I put this code in several test sites and it is working there.  Am I missing something?  Any ideas would be helpful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Found out what it was...

Duh moment really.... I had several of the SVG on the same page and all used the same Mask ID.

Cheers